# move rows up to fill NAs

Tags: r, reshape, na

I'm not sure if I can describe well what I want to do. 
The data file that I get from an experiment looks like this

```
variable1 variable2 variable 3 variable4
23         1         NA         NA
23         0         NA         NA
23         0         NA         NA
23         NA        4          NA
23         NA        3          NA
23         NA        NA         5
23         NA        NA         7
23         NA        NA         1
23         NA        NA         3 
24         1         NA         NA
24         1         NA         NA
24         NA        8          NA
24         NA        3          NA
24         NA        NA         2
24         NA        NA         1
```

So kind of like stairs. The only column that is filled from bottom to top is the first one with the participant id. The others are arranged in order how they appeared in the experiment (three questions for variable 2, then two for variable 3 and four for variable 4).

What I want is to get rid of these NAs (empty fields) and get something like this instead:

```
variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4
23        1         4         5
23        0         3         7
23        0         NA        1
23        NA        NA        3
24        1         8         2
24        1         3         1
```

Can this be done with reshape? Any solution is appreciated

Comment: Did that come from converting a data frame from long to wide? If so, maybe it's better to tackle this while converting to wide

Comment: No that was the original data I got from Pavlovia (the online platform for psychoPy experiments). I didn't do anything to it until now. But I thought about solve it with reshaping

Comment: I assume variable1 will have many values in the actual data?

Comment: Correct, about 100

Comment: Are there several different participant IDs ("variable1"), and non-`NA` values should be moved up _within_ each ID? If so, please provide these details in the actual question.

Comment: yes correct, I added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-variable1) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(grp = seq(n())) %>%
  pivot_wider(c(grp, variable1)) %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4
      <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
1        23         1         4         5
2        23         0         3         7
3        23         0        NA         1
4        23        NA        NA         3
```

if you do not have `pivot_longer/pivot_wider` you could use `gather/spread`:

```
df %>%
   gather(name,values,-variable1) %>% 
   drop_na() %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(grp = seq(n()))%>%
   spread(name,values)%>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4
      <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
1        23         1         4         5
2        23         0         3         7
3        23         0        NA         1
4        23        NA        NA         3
```

In BASE R you could do:

```
(array(df[cbind(c(sapply(df,order)),c(col(df)))],dim(df))->a)[rowSums(!is.na(a))>1,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   23    0    3    1
[2,]   23    0    4    3
[3,]   23    1   NA    5
[4,]   23   NA   NA    7
```

or even:

```
df1 <- transform(na.omit(cbind(df[1],stack(df[-1]))),time = ind, ind = ave(values,ind,FUN=seq_along))
reshape(df1, v.names = "values", dir="wide", idvar = c("variable1","ind"))
   variable1 ind values.variable2 values.variable3 values.variable4
1         23   1                1                4                5
2         23   2                0                3                7
3         23   3                0               NA                1
27        23   4               NA               NA                3
```

Comment: couldn't find the function pivot_longer

Comment: install.packages("tidyr")

Comment: Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  not applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied on objekt of "function"

Comment: Hey @Onyambu unfortunately the gather solution doesn't work as well. But I think with the array we're slowly getting there. Now the numbers moved up, however I also have text in the columns and reaction Times that are in [] this brackets and key presses like this ["z"]. Can you also manage that?
And another thing: I don't want them to be ordered cause for example the word in column 3 belongs to the value in column 4.

Comment: @HonestRlover.not. All the codes provided should work. If you are only using base R, i will recommend the last solution.

Comment: Ok, but the problem remains the same. Everything that is not an integer (text, RT and keypresses) are not there

Comment: @HonestRlover.not. It seems the data you gave was incomplete. Can you ask a new question with the updated data? In that case many will be able to respond to you even if I dont. No one will come back to this question since it has been moved to older posts. You could close this by accepting one of the given answers that satisfy the specified case here.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry. I am going to do this. Really sorry about it. I wanted to keep it simple but I realised you need more to solve the problem

Comment: @HonestRlover.not. feel free to tag me in your new question. Or you could simply post the link here on the chat